# Installing e text editor

Tags: 10.04, compiling

I am trying to get e-text editor to run. I read http://www.e-texteditor.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=14953#14953 and Compile e-text editor on Linux as well. But on my 10.04 Lucid it fails at the following step:

./build_externals_linux.sh debug

with the following error messages:

```
Building debug binaries
Building 32-bit binaries
Going to place output in /opt/etexteditor/external/out.debug
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 41: pushd: bakefile: No such file or directory
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 42: ./configure: No such file or directory
Cannot compile bakefile
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 46: popd: directory stack empty
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 49: pushd: metakit: No such file or directory
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 50: cd: builds: No such file or directory
Cannot compile MetaKit
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 56: popd: directory stack empty
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 59: pushd: pcre: No such file or directory
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 60: ./configure: No such file or directory
Cannot compile pcre
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 66: popd: directory stack empty
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 69: pushd: tinyxml: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
cannot compile TinyXML
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 77: popd: directory stack empty
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 80: pushd: libtommath: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
Cannot compile LTM
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 85: popd: directory stack empty
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 88: pushd: libtomcrypt: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
Cannot compile LTC
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 93: popd: directory stack empty
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 96: pushd: wxwidgets: No such file or directory
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 97: ./configure: No such file or directory
Cannot compile wxWidgets
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 104: popd: directory stack empty
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 107: pushd: webkit: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 109: ./WebKitTools/Scripts/build-webkit: No such file or directory
Cannot compile WebKit
./build_externals_linux.sh: line 113: popd: directory stack empty
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install bakefile, there is no package from the official repositories, try: http://www.bakefile.org/wiki/Debian

Comment: I already have: #Needed for bakefile
"deb http://apt.tt-solutions.com/ubuntu hardy main" in my sources.list and when I try sudo apt-get install bakefile i get "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  bakefile: Depends: python2.5 but it is not installable
E: Broken packages". Does it matter that I'm using lucid?

Comment: Oh, that bakefile repository depends on python2.5 which is obsolete on Lucid :(

Comment: can I specify which python version to use?

Answer (score 0):

1. install bakefile from sources
2. try compiling from latest in http://github.com/tea/e branch

Comment: Could you point me to where I can find a guide to do so? I have checked out the source from svn co https://bakefile.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/bakefile bakefile but the content looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

***Which source files are you using?***

Appears to be answered at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404998/compile-e-text-editor-on-linux

suggests to use:

https://github.com/ajpalkovic/e/tarball/linux